# I need input and help understanding how the formula for x arises in a cycloid that is parameterized with theta with the cusp at the origin

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, parametric, cycloid

Disclaimer: I attempted to answer some of it by using my own deductions. I would feedback on that. The book gives the formulas for how x arises but my problem is understanding how the formulas arose. k: [image: Diagram of Cycloid with the cusp at the origin]

$x = \vert OT \vert - \vert PQ \vert$ $= r\theta - rsin\theta$

where $\vert PQ \vert = rsin(\theta)$

My first problem is understanding where $\vert PQ \vert$ comes from which is really $rsin\theta$

To begin with lets look at the basic property of a ratio between two separate parallel lines, specifically a smaller line and a larger line, this is important because remember sin is really a ratio of two sides specifically the ratio of the opposite to the hypotenuse. Which is a ratio of a smaller line to a larger line:

Lets calle the length of the smaller line $S$ and the length of the larger line $L$ and the ratio $(\frac{S}{L})$, be called $rat$. In relation to the picture $S = PQ$, $L = PC$ (radius),  and  $rat = sin$. Using simple algebra we can see that if we want the length of $S$ then $rat = \frac{S}{L} \Rightarrow (L)rat = \frac{L}{1} \frac{S}{L} \Rightarrow (L)rat = S$ Which from the picture translates to $(PC)sin = \vert PQ \vert$ $\Rightarrow (radius,r)(sin)$ $=$ $\vert PQ\vert$ $\Rightarrow rsin(\theta) = \vert PQ \vert$

Now as for $\vert OT \vert$ I have no explanation as to how that came to equal $r\theta$. Help? A simplified explanation similar to mine would be great. As for the former, did any of that make sense or am I just rambling a bunch of incorrect nonsense that I construed together from lower math to try and justify as to how $\vert PQ \vert$ came to equal $rsin(\theta)$, when in fact that doesn't suffice to explain how the formula arose? If this does make sense then I assume this was left out of the book, because, to anyone skilled in math, all this is implied from the diagram and it is trivial to include? Sometimes I feel like an idiot when trying to grasp math beyond the computation, if I have to go through this much trouble do so, do I belong studying math?

Comment: The length $|OT|$ is equal to the length of the arc $PT$, which is $r\theta$. $|PQ|$ is equal to $r\sin\theta$ because $PQ$ is the opposite leg in the right triangle $PCQ$.

Comment: That second part is the arc length of the sector of a circle of radius r, $s = r \theta$.

Comment: It is good to use your method of deduction. However, you need to understand the definition first. Your first question is not about deduction. It is the definition of cycloid. The purpose is that there is no sliding at contact point, which is important for many machine design such as gear profile.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's easiest if you think about the circle rolling along the x-axis. If you roll it towards the left point P will meet the origin.

Therefore
OT = PT

The arc length PT, which can also be denoted as r (theta) (where theta is in radians), is equal to the distance covered by the circle after point P left the origin.